# Problema al restar puntos con un contador

Tags: lua, corona

He creado este script para restar puntos a un juego, y funciona, pero no como yo quiero, me explico:

"initialtime" me muestra 500 en el display, a este 500 le quiero restar el tiempo transcurrido del contador "clockText" cada vez que "ball" toca "platform". Lo que intento conseguir es que si la pelota toca la plataforma y ha transcurrido 1 segundo, a 500 le descontaría 1 segundo y quedaría 499, pero como el contador sigue en marcha, si han transcurrido 3 segundos, no quiero que le reste 3 segundos a 500, quiero que se lo reste a 499 - 3 = 496, y así sucesivamente:

```
---SI---------|-----------NO
                   |
500 -1-------|---------500 -1        
                   |
499 -3-------|---------499 -3
                   |
496 -5-------|---------497 -5
                   |
 491----------|---------495
```

Concluyendo, la pelota seguiría botando y cada vez que bote, que reste al resultado de  initialtime y no a 500.

El código:

```
local physics = require "physics"
physics.start()

local score = 500

----Initial Time----

    local initialtime = display.newText(score, 100, 200, "Helvetica", 40)


-----Accountant-----

    local clockText = display.newText("000", 100, 300, "Helvetica", 40)

    local secondsLeft = 0 -- secons
    local function updateTime()
    secondsLeft = secondsLeft + 1
    seconds = secondsLeft % 60
    timeDisplay = string.format("%03d", seconds )
    clockText.text = timeDisplay

end

    countDownTimer = timer.performWithDelay( 1000, updateTime, secondsLeft ) 


-----Collision-----

local platform = display.newRect( 0, 0, 280, 30 )
platform.surfaceType = "superbounce"
platform.x, platform.y = display.contentCenterX, display.contentCenterY+200
physics.addBody( platform, "static", { bounce=0.0, friction=0.3 } )

local ball = display.newCircle( 0, 0, 15 )
ball.x, ball.y = display.contentCenterX+100, display.contentCenterY-40
physics.addBody( ball, "dynamic", { bounce=0.0, radius=20 } )

local function onCollision( self, event )

   local collideObject = event.other
   if ( collideObject.surfaceType == "superbounce" ) then
      event.contact.bounce = 1
      print(score - clockText.text)
            initialtime.text = score - clockText.text

   end
end

ball.collision = onCollision
ball:addEventListener( "collision" )
```

---

Ok, Gracias por responder sioesi. Tu idea funciona:

```
score = score - clockText.text
initialtime.text = score
```

Pero me resta el doble de lo que marque clockText. Cuando bota la primera vez y clockText marca 1, a initialtime le restaría 2 en vez de 1:

Primer bote : 500 -1 = 498
Segundo bote: 498 -3 = 492
tercer bote : 492 -5 = 482

Comment: Puedes imprimir los valores de clockText en la funcion updateTime y tambien de timeDisplay

Answer (score 2):

No conozco el lenguaje en si pero me doy cuenta que nunca modificas tu variable `score` solo restas y muestras pero jamas la modificas por ende siempre restara a 500.

```
score = score - clockText.text
initialtime.text = score
```

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo he resuelto utilizando json, insertando la puntuación en puntoData[1] y recuperándola después:

```js
------------------------------SALVAR PUNTOS EN puntos.json--

   local puntoData = {}
   puntoData[1] = initialtime.text - clockText.text
   loadsave.saveTable(puntoData,"puntos.json", system.DocumentsDirectory)
         
------------RESCATAR PUNTOS DE puntos.json Y MOSTRARLOS EN initialtime.text------
  
      puntoData = loadsave.loadTable("puntos.json", system.DocumentsDirectory)
         
local function puntuacion(event)                                            
                   initialtime.text = puntoData[1]
               end 
                   tiempoPuntos = timer.performWithDelay( 100, puntuacion )
```